# Bespoke form on Django - dropdown menu matching models choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a form with all sorts of headers and question before each field.

I initially create a form in Forms.py, but it seems quite difficult to customise it the way I want it.

I resorted to build the form in the html template.

I am struggling to create a drop down menu.

In this example, when selecting the colour, users would have 4 choices listed in the choices in models.py. I am clearly not linking the form in the template to the actual form.

What am I doing wrong?

(I should say, I saw a couple of things on here about fieldsets, but I dont understand the actual solutions explained)

Here is the code
**Models.py**

```
LOOKCOLOUR=(
    (1,'Straw'),
    (2,'Yellow'),
    (3,'Gold'),
    (4,'Amber'),
)


class ChampageRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="champcomments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    look_colour=models.IntegerField(choices=LOOKCOLOUR, default=0)
    ..

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s'%(self.user, self.product, self.date_added)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ElderFlowerChampForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ChampageRating
        fields = ('look_colour', )
        labels ={
            'look_colour': 'Colour',

        }

        widgets = {
                    'look_colour':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                }
```

**views.py**

```
def elderflowerchamp(request, product_id):
    global ChampageRating
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    submitted = False
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            reviews = ChampageRating.objects.get(pk=product_id)
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                form = ElderFlowerChampFormAdmin(request.POST, instance=reviews)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('home')
            else:
                form = ElderFlowerChampForm(request.POST, instance=reviews)
                if form.is_valid():
                    ChampageRating = form.save(commit=False)
                    ChampageRating.user = request.user
                    ChampageRating.save()
                    return redirect('home')
        else:
            #This part goes to the page, but doesnt submit
            reviews = ChampageRating.objects.get(pk=product_id)
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                form = ElderFlowerChampFormAdmin
            else:
                form = ElderFlowerChampForm
            if 'submitted' in request.GET:
                submitted = True
    except:
        reviews = None
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            form = ElderFlowerChampFormAdmin(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    data = ChampageRating()
                    data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
                    data.look_colour = form.cleaned_data['look_colour']
                    data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                    data.product_id = product_id
                    data.user_id = request.user.id
                    data.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been submitted.')
                    return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = ElderFlowerChampForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    data = ChampageRating()
                    data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
                    data.look_colour = form.cleaned_data['look_colour']
                    data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                    data.product_id = product_id
                    data.user_id = request.user.id
                    data.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been submitted.')
                    return redirect('home')
```

**template**

```
<form action="{% url 'ElderFlowerReview' product.id%}" method="POST">
                {%csrf_token%}
                <h4>Look</h4>
                <h5>Colour</h5>
                <select name="look_colour" rows="4" class="form-control"></select>
               

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone comes across the same problem, I kinda found the solution. (it creates new problems, but it's a start).

Source here: https://github.com/hadpro24/django-forms-fieldset

Here is what I did.

**I installed fieldsets (thats the part I was missing on other posts)**

```
pip install django-forms-fieldset
```

**I added fieldsets in the installed apps (in setting.py)**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
,
    'forms_fieldset']
```

**in forms.py Fieldsets need to be added before Meta**

```
class ElderFlowerChampFormAdmin(ModelForm):
    fieldsets=[
            ("Look",{'fields':[
            ('look_colour','look_clarity','look_effervescence')]}),
          ]
    class Meta:
        model = ChampageRating
        fields = ('user','look_colour', ..)
        
        labels ={
            'user': '',
            'product': '',
            'look_colour': '',
        }
        widgets = {
                    'user': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                    'look_colour':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                }
```

**then in the template**

```
{% load forms_fieldset static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'forms_fieldset/css/main.css' %}">
      <form  action="{% url '#' product.id%}"method = POST>
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{ form|fieldset}}
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Add Review</button>
      </form>
```